# Power BI :: calculate a FORECAST in DAX till a specific date

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a line chart that shows me how much I spend per day. Below that a Matrix that shows me how much I spent per month:

[image]

I would like to see that line to go till the end of the year (`31/12/2023`)

**OUT OF SCOPE:** using the default Forecast provided by the Line Chart is out of scope because it will not reflect the numbers in the Matrix.

I need to calculate it with `DAX`.

If you want to help me you can download the files here :

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=0FLHsi)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=hGrvT5)

Thank you